# How can I set my own taxonomy order in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy

Perhaps I'm missing something but is there an easy way to set the order of terms in a custom taxonomy without using a plugin?

At the moment, it's ordering them alphabetically e.g.

Apples
Bananas
Cherries

But I want to set my own custom order - not based on ID, count or any other built-in orderby argument in Wordpress. Like:

Bananas
Cherries
Apples

My code is below. I've included the tag IDs in the order I want but it doesn't work:

```
'taxonomy' => 'car_listing_tag', 
'include' => '30,25,46,11,45', 
'orderby' => 'ID'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard without seeing your whole code; also your question is open to a lot of debate. Please try to be as specific as you can so we don't mistake ourselves when answering as well. 
if I understood correctly, you're doing a term query on WordPress, this is a basic one you can use

```
    // WP_Term_Query arguments
$args = array(
    'taxonomy'               => array( 'car_listing_tags' ),
    'slug'                   => array( 'term-slug', 'term-slug2', 'term-slug3', 'term-slug4', 'term-slug5' ),
    'order'                  => 'ASC',
    'orderby'                => 'id',
);

// The Term Query
$car_listing_tag = new WP_Term_Query( $args );
```

The orderby filter accepts `id/slug/term name/term description/term group/count`.
You will still need to add the loop after this, based on your question seems like you already have something.

Comment: Thanks mate. I had no idea you could order by term description. I just edited that to suit the order I needed.